# CreateFile fails in wxWidgets

Tags: windows, winapi, wxwidgets

I am trying to open the serial port, Below is the code and the CreateFile always return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Can someone help me this.

```
wxString port = "COM13";

HANDLE hComm = CreateFile( port.wc_str(),  
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                0, 
                NULL, 
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                NULL);

if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    WxListBox_Log->Append("Unable to connect " + port.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following file name: `"\\\\.\\COM13"`.

See details in this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831

HOWTO: Specify Serial Ports Larger than COM9